# Pass function requiring parameter to PureComponent properly

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using FlatList and in my renderItem I have a PureComponent called GridItem. I am trying to pass the function wishlistAddPresed which requires the item parameter, however when done this way, the PureComponent items are all rerendering on every state change even if "item" has not changed.

How do I fix this? Thank you!

```
  wishlistAddPresed = (item) => console.log(item)

  renderItem = ({item}) => {
    return (
        <GridItem
            item={item}
            wishlistAddPresed={this.wishlistAddPresed(item)}
        />
    )
  }

  render () {
      console.log("Render products grid");
      return(
          <View style={styles.container}>
              <FlatList
                  data={this.state.data}
                  renderItem={this.renderItem}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
              />
          </View>
      );
  }
```

In my GridItem's render I have:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.colButtonsG} onPress={this.props.wishlistAddPresed}>
    <IconG name='playlist-add-check' size={26} color="green" style={styles.icon} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I think you need to change `wishlistAddPresed={this.wishlistAddPresed(item)}` to `wishlistAddPresed={this.wishlistAddPresed}`. With the code you provided I can't see anything particularly wrong.

Comment: When I do that, the "item" in wishlistAddPresed isn't the item from my renderItem.

Comment: Then `wishlistAddPresed={() => this.wishlistAddPresed(item)}` should mean you are getting the correct item, the issue is that if you have `{this.wishlistAddPresed(item)}` it is being called on every render rather than when 'Wishlist add' is pressed. Let me know if this helps and I'll add this as the answer.

Comment: That appears to have the same effect as what I have. The function wishlistAddPresed works as expected, but all GridItems are being rerendered on every state change even if their item prop doesn't change.

Comment: I was using shouldComponentUpdate before with Component but was trying to avoid writing the function many times if I can use PureComponents instead. Thank you for you assistance by the way. I think for now I may need to stick with writing shouldComponentUpdate if what I need cannot be done with PureComponent.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to pass both the callback function AND the parameter (which you are already doing) and then *inside* the nested component, pass the item to an anonymous callback. So in your case, you would need to do the following:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
    return <GridItem item={item} wishlistAddPressed={this.wishlistAddPressed} />
  }}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

And for the GridItem which extends PureComponent...

```
class GridItem extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {item, wishlistAddPresed} = this.props;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => wishlistAddPressed(item)}>
        <IconG name="playlist-add-check" size={26} color="green" style={styles.icon} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Done this way, `wishlistAddPressed` gets called with the specific item for that row and the function equality is maintained so that the PureComponent doesn't re-render improperly like it should.